# How to add adsurl field as link to bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

For each paper at SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System (ADS) a BibTeX entry is provided containing a field like

```
adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015EPJST.224.2217S},
```

which I would like to add as link in the bibliography of my LaTeX document.

It seemed like there is no simple way to do this in BibTeX but that it should be possible with `biblatex`. How?

Comment: If you use BibTeX, which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: I use different styles for example aa.bst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I found a satisfying solution based on an additional comment in [How can I cut, strip, truncate or rename parts of bibtex fields with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287229/how-can-i-cut-strip-truncate-or-rename-parts-of-bibtex-fields-with-biblatex). Now it looks as follows:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=5,minbibnames=5]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{adsurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{adsurl}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=adsurl, match={http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/},
        replace={}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{ADSURL: \href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/#1}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{adsurl}\finentry}

\let\cite\textcite  %for compatibility of \cite/\citep with bibtex
```

And it produces something like:

```
Kundu, M. R. (1965). Solar radio astronomy. New York: Interscience Publication,
1965. ADSURL: 1965sra..book.....K.
```

where [1965sra..book.....K](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1965sra..book.....K) is a link.

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround just for the A&A journal. I modified `aa.bst` file and use the `adsurl` entry and `doi` entry to create clickable hyperlinks. You can download the new `aa_url.bst` here: https://github.com/yangcht/AA-bibstyle-with-hyperlink

just replace the `aa.bst` with `aa_url.bst`

An example is here: 
[image]

Note that do please use the bib entry generated by the ADS website.

Answer (score 2):

In biblatex it is possible to define new bibtex fields. New fields can be created using `\DeclareDatamodelFields` and `\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes` (these commands should appear in a  biblatex configuration file, a simple ways is to is to use `filecontents` to create such configuration file while processing a document)

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{adsurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[proceedings,inproceedings]{adsurl}
\end{filecontents}
```

The second step is to specify how it is going to be rendered. For example,

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{#1}
```

and then add

```
\printfield[bibhyperref]{adsurl}
```

in the drivers/bibmacro for the entries where  the field should be printed. The following simply add the `adsurl` at the end of an bibliography entry in the bibliography.

```
\newbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield[bibhyperref]{adsurl}\finentry}
```

Comment: Note that if you override the default field format with the optional argument as in `\printfield[bibhyperref]{adsurl}` there is no point in having a `\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{#1}` in the first place. Furthermore, I think `bibhyperref` is not the correct format here, it is used to link back to the bibliography entry form a citation. I would probably go `\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{\mkbibacro{ADSURL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{adsurl}\finentry}` or so. Instead of the datatype `verbatim` one could even use `uri`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which seems to work.
But is \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields actually needed?
Is there also a way to remove "http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/" from every entry?

Comment: I have asked this as [How can I cut, strip, truncate or rename parts of bibtex fields with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287229/how-can-i-cut-strip-truncate-or-rename-parts-of-bibtex-fields-with-biblatex).