# How can I cut, strip, truncate or rename parts of bibtex fields with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

How can I truncate `http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/` from every `adsurl` field that looks like

```
adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015EPJST.224.2217S}.
```

Could it be accomplished by changing the rendering

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{#1}
```

I would like the field to appear as link at the end of a reference as

**Author (year), Title, ...,  ADS: [2015EPJST.224.2217S](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015EPJST.224.2217S)**

This question appeared in [How to add adsurl field as link to bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286704/how-to-add-adsurl-field-as-link-to-bibliography).

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281294/biblatex-string-manipulation-after-processing-of-bibtex-string help? The idea is the same, you just need to pick the appropriate field and search/replace (and use Biber).

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to make it more clear what I want. I don't know how to do this from your reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like I found a first solution based on the comment by Joseph Wright by cutting the text first and adding it later as follows

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{adsurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{adsurl}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=adsurl, match={http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/},
        replace={}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{ADSURL: \href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/#1}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\printfield{adsurl}\finentry}
```

And it produces something like:

```
Kundu, M. R. (1965). Solar radio astronomy. New York: Interscience Publication,
1965. ADSURL: 1965sra..book.....K.
```

While [1965sra..book.....K](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1965sra..book.....K) is a link. See [How to add adsurl field as link to bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286704/how-to-add-adsurl-field-as-link-to-bibliography).

I am wondering if this is the simplest way of doing it.